# Is it possible to use "extraordinaire" instead of "extraordinary"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives

Since they are both adjectives, is it possible to use them interchangeably on various occasions? When is the right time to use *extraordinaire*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*[Extraordinaire](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extraordinaire)* and *[extraordinary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extraordinary)* are of similar meaning, both meaning  exceptional, unusual, out of the ordinary.  However, as explained in wiktionary's [usage notes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extraordinaire#Usage_notes),

> Following the manner of French adjectives, and unlike most English adjectives, extraordinaire follows its subject [for example] Charlie Parker, saxophonist extraordinaire, released many records.

Generally, use *extraordinaire* if you want to put the adjective after the modified noun, want to make the noun sound more like a title, and want to add a touch of foreign flavor to the sentence.  Use  *extraordinary* if you want to put the adjective before the modified noun and communicate in an ordinary tone of voice.

Note that in a few cases,  *extraordinary* also is used as an adjective  after the  noun.  Example:
*[Ambassador Extraordinary and Plenipotentiary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambassador_Extraordinary_and_Plenipotentiary#Ambassador_Extraordinary_and_Plenipotentiary)*

Answer (score 9):

As already noted, in some contexts the two terms are interchangeable - apart from the fact that, being essentially just a co-opted French word, *extraordinaire* comes after the noun, not before.

But to me the most significant difference is that an *xxxx extraordinaire* is invariably "positive", and normally means an unusually ***fine*** example of xxxx. Whereas an *extraordinary xxxx* may simply mean an xxxx who happens to be unusual in some way - possibly in a negative sense, or unusual in some respect that doesn't directly relate to the fact of being an xxxx in the first place.

For example, whimsical/facetious usages aside, if you read of a [saxophonist extraordinaire](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pianist%20extraordinaire%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22saxophonist%20extraordinaire%22&oq=%22saxophonist%20extraordinaire%22&gs_l=serp.3...32221.36864.0.37224.18.18.0.0.0.1.99.1086.18.18.0...0.0...1c.1.nd5oWCC1PiU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1149&bih=864), you can be sure the writer believes his subject to be unusually talented - with the strong implication that many/most other fans of the instrument would agree with that assessment. But an [extraordinary saxophonist](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pianist%20extraordinaire%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22extraordinary%20saxophonist%22&oq=%22extraordinary%20saxophonist%22&gs_l=serp.3...287832.293621.1.295077.9.9.0.0.0.0.126.486.8j1.9.0...0.0...1c.1.WGR43Xck2hg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1149&bih=864) might be unusual just because he has a non-standard playing technique. Or exhibits some bizarre quirk, such as always appearing on stage wearing a motor-cycle helmet.

Relating to that distinction, an [extraordinary man](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pianist%20extraordinaire%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22an%20extraordinary%20man%22&oq=%22an%20extraordinary%20man%22&gs_l=serp.3...503622.509606.2.510027.17.17.0.0.0.0.114.925.16j1.17.0...0.0...1c.1.t10z6CwhBAQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1149&bih=864) wouldn't normally convey the same thing as a [man extraordinaire](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pianist%20extraordinaire%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22a%20man%20extraordinaire%22&oq=%22a%20man%20extraordinaire%22&gs_l=serp.3...96829.103227.3.103675.14.14.0.0.0.0.95.799.14.14.0...0.0...1c.1.FrAX7hq1JAE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1149&bih=864). That second one is very much an [extraordinary expression](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pianist%20extraordinaire%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22an%20extraordinary%20expression%22&oq=%22an%20extraordinary%20expression%22&gs_l=serp.3...32491.42146.10.42493.35.30.0.0.0.3.313.2094.27j2j0j1.30.0...0.0...1c.1.WvkbnLRqxTU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1149&bih=864), and I can't even find any relevant written instances of an [expression extraordinaire](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pianist%20extraordinaire%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22an%20expression%20extraordinaire%22&oq=%22an%20expression%20extraordinaire%22&gs_l=serp.3...6867.7571.9.7872.3.3.0.0.0.0.78.169.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.ZfJl1psB-jk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1149&bih=864).

Comment: Also, using 'extraordinaire' is much much rarer than 'extraordinary' and being French has a pretentious air to it, like you're advertising for a circus.

Comment: @Mitch: Another lesson in British understatement: *"just a co-opted French word"* is supposed to fully convey that disparagement (and then some! :)

Comment: A wink is as good as a nod to a blind horse.

Comment: @Mitch: In the land of blind horses, [the one-eyed donkey is king](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22one-eyed+man+is+king%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (or would that be *"one-eyed ass"* in the US? :)

Comment: We don't have asses in the US...

Comment: Not blind ones, maybe, but increasing numbers of [dumbasses](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dumbass&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: We _do_ know [the difference between that and a hole in the ground](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dumbass%2Casshole&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3)

Comment: I suppose I must have heard [that one](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22difference+between%22+%22and+a+hole+in+the+ground%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) before, but certainly not very often. I'm more used to [you don't know the difference between your arse and your **elbow**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22difference+between+your+arse+and+your+elbow%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Answer (score -1):

extraordinaire can used sarcastically and its French origin can signal a lampooning quality.  For example, "The councilman was the mayor's sycophant extraordinaire."  This usage carries an more pejorative connotation than merely saying that "The Councilman was an extraordinarily sycophant."