# How to use “extraordinaire” in English?

Tags: adjectives, grammatical-number, subject-verb-inversion, french

I’d like to include the following phrase in my children’s book:

> with trumpets and fanfares **extraordinaire**

I don’t know whether it should instead be

> with trumpets and fanfares **extraordinaires**

Should I write that with or without the silent *s* at the end?

Comment: I'd advise against using it in a children's book for Anglophones unless they live in Belgium, Canada, Chad, New Orleans, or Switzerland, and no "s" on the end if you must include it. I like the [M-W-online example sentence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extraordinaire): _the sort of chef extraordinaire who can whip up a fantastic meal, regardless of the ingredients on hand_. Any use not analogous to this one seems gratuitous & pretentious to me. But that's only because I love French.

Comment: Don't use it in English unless you can speak French. And don't pluralize it in English; English adjectives don't inflect for plural.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use "extraordinaire" instead of "extraordinary"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100413/is-it-possible-to-use-extraordinaire-instead-of-extraordinary)

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you are French. :)

I would definitely suggest that you not include the silent *s*, as English speakers will find this confusing. Even though the idiomatic placement of the word *extraordinaire* after the noun is derived from french, I don’t think the silent *s* would be as well.